# I can't get my Wacom Intuos to work in Ubuntu at all

Tags: command-line, compiling, wacom, graphics-tablet

I just bought a new Wacom Intuos, and I can't get anything to work. The tablet itself turns on, and detects pressure, but the cursor won't even move even though lsusb detects it. I have an older model that works fine. I'm on Ubuntu 14.4.

I've tried downloading Xf86-input-wacom from [here](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and I get this error when I try to `./configure`:

```
Package xorg-macros was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-macros.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-macros' found
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for doxygen... no
configure: WARNING: doxygen not found - documentation targets will be skipped
checking for rint in -lm... yes
checking for XORG... no
configure: error: Package requirements (xorg-server >= 1.7.0 xproto xext kbproto inputproto randrproto) were not met:

No package 'xorg-server' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XORG_CFLAGS
and XORG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XF86 Driver shouldn't need updating, though the input-wacom driver might.

Which tablet (lsusb output) and which ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Here's what it says in lsusb: Bus 001 Device 027: ID 056a:00b1 Wacom Co., Ltd Intuos3 6x18

Also, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty LTS)

Comment: Actually, I just updated/installed the driver you just mentioned, and it all works now! Thanks! :)